Is it possible to trigger Drop event in JavaScript[chrome extension]
I am writing a Chrome extension to intercept the drop event and analyze the files being dropped, using Event.DataTransfer, and re-trigger the drop event with a modified file list.
Am I doing this right, or is there any other way to achieve this?
function dropHandler(Event)
{
    //Collect the files from Event.DataTransfer
    //Send it to background.js
    //prevent Default
    //Stop the Propagation()
}

onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) =>
{
    //Create a new Drop Event.
    //Initialize a new DataTransfer Object with the file list.
    //Updates the new DropEvent  with the newly initialized DataTransfer object
    //Trigger the drop event.
});

Unfortunately, the drop event is getting triggered but the file is not getting attached to the website.

Given that DataTransfer.files is a readonly property, I'm not sure how you're expecting this to work? Can you please edit the question to provide all the relevant code.

Hi Roy, Thanks. I understand it is readyonly, but if you create a new DataTransfer object, then I'm able to populate the files in it.   My requirement is to capture the drop event/stop propagating it further and process the files in the background.js in async way.   The background.js on processing, sends the response back to the  extension.js.  The extension.js should trigger a drop event/or any other event to continue uploading of files.
